# Let $ H \lt G $ such that $ [a,b] \subset H $. Then H is a normal subgroup of G

Tags: group-theory

Let $ H \lt G $ such that $ [a,b] \subset H .$ Then $H$ is a normal subgroup of G .

I am not sure if what i did was a good way to proceed.

Proof. Let $ a,b \in G, $ and $ aba^{-1}b^{-1}  \in G' $ (the commutator of G). By hypothesis, $ aba^{-1}b^{-1}  \in G' $ also implies that $ aba^{-1}b^{-1}  \in H. $ I am supposed to prove that $gxg^{-1} \in H $, where $ x =  aba^{-1}b^{-1} $.

So $ gxg^{-1} = g(aba^{-1}b^{-1})g^{-1} = (gag^{-1})(gbg^{-1})(ga^{-1}g^{-1})(gb^{-1}g^{-1})(gg^{-1}).$ If I knew that each of these factors lives in $H$, then I would know that the multiplication is also in $H$, because $H$ is a subgroup. But I don't think I really know that $gag^{-1}$ is in $H$.

Comment: What are $a$, $b$, and $[a,b]$?

Comment: $a,b$ are elements in $G$ and $[a,b]=G' ,$ the commutator of $G$.

Comment: I think $[a,b]$ standardly denotes the commutator of the two elements, for the derived subgroup you can use $G'$ or $[G,G]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean that $[a,b] \in H $ for all $a,b \in G $. Then if $g \in G, x\in H $, $gxg^{-1} = x x^{-1}gxg^{-1} = x [x^{-1},g] \in H $.